# S3-redshift spectrum with streaming data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, amazon-redshift-spectrum

Problem statement - I have streaming data coming in a S3 bucket. So, they are essentially JSON files. I would want to use this data with the other tables in redshift(perform joins)

Here are the options:

1. Use lambda with a trigger for every S3 object created. The lambda will run a copy command to move the data to redshift.
   Problem here - What if there are a lot of connections open to redshift and this causes a problem?
2. Use redshift spectrum - Design a glue crawler, that will run every 15 mins, and check for new partitions
   Problem here - What if  the crawler runs , while the previous instance of the crawler is still running? And this is not real time..
3. Should I use Kinesis Firehose?
   Problem - I do not want to maintain this data on redshift but would like it on S3, as the data is huge. I also want to join this data in S3 with other redshift tables. So, I cant use Athena too

Any ideas on this please?

Comment: How large are each S3 object being created?  (order of magnitude) - Millions of small objects is an S3 anti-pattern and you will need to rethink your data architecture.

Comment: Bill, as of now, there would be an ~50k objects per day

Comment: what is the size of these objects?

Comment: Bill, each file would be less than 50kb

Comment: This is a pattern I've seen before and you are headed for trouble.  S3 takes about .5 sec to find an object somewhere in the mesh that is S3 and this is BEFORE any data transfer occurs.  In 20 days you have a million objects.  In a year you will have above 15 million.  Add up all those half seconds and you will see the problem.  S3 data stores need to have objects of more than 100MB to hide this attribute of S3.  This means some kind of aggregating of data files in your data flow.  You can use Redshift to do this if you like - COPY many files in, UNLOAD the data in fewer files.

Comment: Apologies for the delayed response @BillWeiner. I was doing a POC. I used redshift spectrum and I see that the data is immediately reflected in the external table soon as the object arrives on S3. I just need to run the crawler once a day, and no matter how may files I add for that day, the data is immediately reflected. May I know what do you think if this please?

Comment: The issue I'm concerned you will run into is the access time of all these objects when most are being accessed in the same query.  With Spectrum S3 workers do the initial access of the objects and these can be more than the number of Redshift slices - this helps.  However, as you bucket grows with millions and millions of 50K objects the time to scan this information will become extreme.  This is due to the small object size and the overhead of referencing each one.  S3 objects used for large data repo should be at least 100MB in size to outweigh this overhead.

Comment: hi @BillWeiner. The objects will sit in S3 partition. I will most usually scan all the objects in a certain partition. Will this still cause a problem?Apart from the sizing of the object, is the spectrum option reliable?

Comment: The nature of an object store is that the file locations are "hashed" from "name" information and located somewhere within a cluster.  S3 is a very large cluster of computers (with very large storage attached) and locating the requested files from this cluster requires performing a hash look up and assigning a node to deliver the file. This takes more time that referencing a file from a disk on your computer.  Once you spend this time to file a file it is ideal to spend some time delivering it.  Reading a lot of small files just means that you spend all your time looking up and not delivering.

Comment: It is simple math - if you have 100K files that need to be read from s3 to perform some action and you have 32 parallel readers (slices), then the minimum time to refence these files is 100,000 * .5 (sec) / 32 which is 15K seconds or 26 minutes.  The time to transfer 10,000, 50KB objects over these same 32 parallel connections is 10K * 50K / (32 * 125,000 (MB/sec)) which is 125 seconds or 2 min.  There is no way around this UNLESS you store fewer, larger (100MB or larger) objects.  You are heading for trouble on the path you are on.

Comment: Understood @BillWeiner. Thank you. So, if I leave the S3 and redshift spectrum out. What about the approaches I have mentioned on lambda(option 1) and kinesis(option 3)?

Comment: It doesn't leave Spectrum out, it just means you need a different S3 organization.  You want files of about 1GB in size instead of 50KB, or at least get closer to 1GB say 10MB minimum.  This becomes a flow rate problem against the solution requirements.  Simplest solution would be to periodically read recent data into (COPY or Spectrum) and write new, larger files out to S3.  You can even change to parquet format for performance enhancement.  This could be controlled by a Lambda.  All 3 of your options can be part of the same solution.

Comment: thanks @BillWeiner. It's just that the data is expected to be in real time. So, if I merge the incoming files  into larger files and then process them, the expectation of real time is not met. This is where I am worried

Comment: You could use a hybrid approach. Each day (or whatever the right interval is) you combine files but for for data since the last "combine" action you use the raw /small objects. This keeps the number of objects reasonable but allows spectrum to scan newest files.  A few corner cases to work out but should work